# What's the best way to add new fields to WP user profiles in the back end?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to be able to keep a file on each of my site users on my WP site. Each user is a volunteer, and I want to be able to ask them questions on the phone and edit their user profile with a number of things. That said, I would like to add custom fields to the user profiles without buying a premium plugin to do the job. (FYI, I've already tried Participant's Database, and it doesn't add new members as site users. I'm not interested in doing a bunch of AJAX coding to figure it out either). Any suggestions? Any plugins other than buddypress or profile builder?

Comment: Are you just trying to add new fields to the user profile page on the backend?

Comment: Yes. The users don't even need to see them, let alone change them. I just want something for me to see on the backend, but I need different types of inputs including textareas, dropdowns, and checkboxes. Any ideas?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/ should work.